# How to get a child's data when it has been pushed?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using the "push()" function to store objects into my firebase database and since it stores data with unique keys I can't change the stored objects values using what's mentionned in the documentation:

```
myRef.child("child name").setValue(model);
```

because I simply don't know the key. I wan wondering is there an other way to modify the data of firebase database.

I want to add a new child called "conversations" to the users and programmatically add childs to him .

and this is the databse structure:

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure and indicate the exact data that you want to get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the following database:

```
 Users
    pushId
        name : john
        age  : 100
```

In case you dont know the `pushId`, you can do the following:

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
         String key = ds.getKey();
         String name = ds.child("name").getValue().toString();
     }
}

 @Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
 }
});
```

The above will get you the `name` and the key using `getKey()`

Comment: Imagine if I want to get a specific user's name using its id and I have millions of users do I have to loop inside all of the users to just get one

Comment: no you use a query `orderByChild("name").equalTo(UserName_Here)`

Comment: `databaseReference.orderByChild("name").equalTo(UserName_Here).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){....)`